# Sampling with replacement only on failures

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables

Suppose we have the hypergeometric distribution scenario, population size $N$, $K$ objects with a favorable feature. We draw $n$ times until $k$ successes but for each success we remove a $K$-type object from the population. We're increasing our chance of drawing an $(x+1)$-th object if we draw the $x$-th one by a bit by making the population smaller but decrease it by a another bit by removing one of the sought objects from the pile. Is this a known distribution? What's the PMF?

The original problem has multiple types of objects each with different weights assigned to them which point to [Fisher's noncentral hypergeometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%27s_noncentral_hypergeometric_distribution) so if you have the answer to the general problem too you're welcome to share it.

Answer (score 1):

It $N$ denotes the number of trials needed for achieving $k$ successes then: $$N=X_1+\cdots+X_k$$ where the $X_i$ are independent and every $X_i$ has geometric distribution with parameter $p_i=\frac{K+1-i}{N+1-i}$.

In that sense the distribution is "known".

But finding its PMF seems to me quite a job.

I would only go after it if there are signals that it might be fruitful for some reason.

Comment: Why is finding the PMF quite a job? Can't I use convolution of $k$ random variables? Am I missing something basic? Yes the expression would be tedious, yet computable. What about the more general problem I added?

Comment: Here "tedious" is enough for me to call it "quite a job". I have not observed any indications that you missed something. Further I did not look at the general problem and it is not excluded that I will not do that. I am not so fond on tedious calculations.